# Switch windows in JavaFX in built artifact project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm trying to switch windows in JavaFX properly. 
I have 3 screens and if I run my application in Intellij IDEA, I can switch them without any problems. But when I build JavaFX Application artifact and open the app without IDE, it opens main window with `MainWindowController`, but doesn't switch to other screens. How must I change my code?

### Here is the code that switches between `MainWindow` and `TestWindow`

```
try {
     new TestWindow(editYName.getText(), sex);
     startButton.getScene().getWindow().hide();
} catch (IOException e) {
     Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
     alert.show();
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Run the application from the command prompt and check for errors.

Comment: We cannot help you with the given amout of code. You need to include any error occuring and the minimal code required to reproduce the error in the question. Right now there is just this constructor invocation that ***could*** be responsible for showing a new window...

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam, thank you. I forgot to test my app in command prompt. It pruduces NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: Then the problem is classpath. Check which class is not found and add it in the classpath

Comment: @fabian, OK. I would edit my question if I won't pass it myself. Thank you too:)